# Listing database and table names in a database?

Tags: mysql, database

I'm thinking of making a sandbox system for clients to preview website projects. I'd like to make a UI for myself/coworker(s) to add projects and clients to a database. Some of these projects require their own databases.

Let's say a client wants a WordPress based blog - they need a database. So, my system will allow the admin to create the requisite database. Now, in *my sandbox system*, I want to keep track of which dummy databases belong to which users.

Is it a bad idea to keep a table of databases that are per project? Is my whole concept unsound?

Comment: Can you be a little bit cleared with your question. I don't fully grasp what it is you are asking.

Comment: @Khez - Sure, what don't you understand?

Comment: Try rephrasing your question, I don't get if you're if it's a bad idea to have a DB GUI to create tables/databases or if it's a bad idea to save the results(?) in a db. or something else entirely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is necessary because you can just run [`SHOW DATABASES`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/show-databases.html) to retrieve all the database names.

To retrieve the tables for a given database, you can run:

```
SHOW TABLES FROM db_name;
```

Comment: Interesting point, but what if I want to keep track of which databases "belong" to which clients?

Comment: You can prefix the database names with the client name, for example. `mikelewis_databasename`. You can then do a query using `LIKE`: `SHOW DATABASES LIKE 'mikelewis%'`

Comment: Another interesting idea. :-)